How do you counteract wriggling wrecks?
A wriggling wreck is an anomaly found in Damp Forest and Blistering Woods junctions. It's a pile of scrap metal that moves slightly. If you get too close to one, it will surround you with several Minutemen anomalies which deal shock damage if you get too close, and after a short period, it will let out a pulse of energy which deals shock damage to you and/or your car.
Is there a way to avoid being damaged by this anomaly, or is it unavoidable once it has been triggered?

There's a couple of ways you can deal with wriggling wrecks: One by paying attention and another by using upgrades to your advantage.
Wriggling wrecks often have smoke appearing out of them, which can be useful to identify and avoid them in clear weather. If one gets triggered, there is often a gap in the Minutemen that it spawns, usually behind you. Using the handbrake and reversing is often enough to avoid getting damaged. If all else fails, drive through the Minutemen, they hurt a lot less than the wriggling wreck's pulse.
The Lightning Rod upgrade can be used to absorb damage from attacks that arc electricity. This means you can avoid damage from the spawned Minutemen (and they'll also charge your batteries!). You can also use the Jump Jack upgrade to jump over the wriggling wreck and avoid it altogether at the right speed.
